# Ubuntu Wipe Command

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Is there a way to wipe the hard drive through terminal but keep the Ubuntu installation. In other words I want to keep the Ubuntu installation but just delete all packages installed user data. (fresh install of Ubuntu)

Thanks, Void.

Comment: Your question is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why in the world you would ever, ever want to do such a thing, but, if you truly must:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/*
```

This command deletes everything in your `Home/<username>/` folder. I would seriously, seriously advise against this. Whatever problem you're facing. please consider other options first, because this could be a huge mistake. I can't think of any reason for wiping everything besides your installation. If you really, really must do so, this is how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, my reasoning is that I have over cluttered my server with packages and now need a fresh install of ubuntu server on this pc. I have no way of accessing the bios etc, so I am hoping there is a command to kind of fresh install ubuntu. I do not just want to clean the home directory.

Comment: It's not necessary to access the BIOS directly. So long as you have a boot USB drive, you can just reinstall the whole thing fresh. If you're already using Ubuntu as it is, just find an 8 Gb USB stick, use GParted to format it, then UNetBootin to install the *.iso file onto the USB as a bootable disk image, and just reinstall that way. Usually, when the computer is starting up, you press either Esc, F2, F8, or F10 in order to choose what to boot up from. From there, you choose the USB drive option, and proceed as necessary.